# How to remove 0's from the second column

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this :

```
k141_173024,001
k141_173071,002
k141_173527,021
k141_173652,034
k141_173724,041
...
```

How do I remove 0's from each line of the second field?
The desired result is :

```
k141_173024,1
k141_173071,2
k141_173527,21
k141_173652,34
k141_173724,41
...
```

What I've tied was

```
cut -f 2 -d ',' file |  awk '{print $1 + 0} > file2

cut -f 1 -d ',' file > file1

paste file1 file2 > final_file
```

This was an inefficient way to edit it.
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? What are the other conditions? Can `0` occur anywhere in the second field or only in the beginning?

Comment: There are always 3 charchters in the second field separated by , . Oops, I forgot to post what I've tried. I won't forget next time. Thank you!

Comment: @SuminKim, you can still share what you have tried by editing the post.

Comment: Ok, @Clock Slave, I will edit it right away! Thank you.

Comment: You knew that adding 0 to $1 would modify the 1st field of the file as you want, so modifying the 2nd field of the file by [adding 0 to $2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038864/how-to-remove-0s-from-the-second-column#comment92989040_53039000) should have been pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I see that ;) Thank you for your feedback! @Ed Morton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/0/,"",$2)}1' Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** To remove only leading zeros try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^0+/,"",$2)}1'  Input_file
```

Comment: This sorked perfectly for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: This will remove all zeroes, not just the leading ones.

Comment: @codeforester, I thought OP needs to remove all zeros, thanks for letting know I added another solution too now.

Comment: I tried the edited code and it now seems flawless. Thank you!

Comment: @SuminKim, sure cool, glad that it helped you, give it sometime and select an answer as correct answer out of all to close the thread completely.

Comment: Got it! :) Thank you!

Comment: That will fail when `$2` **is** `0` since it'll convert it to a null string.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 OFS $2+0}' Input.txt
```

Force to Integer value by adding 0

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1,$2+0}' Input.txt` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2=$2+0' Input.txt` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2+=0' Input.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus, the last two options will fail if `$2` is zero

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2+=0} 1'`

Comment: @kvantour: Good catch. Almost all the answers here have the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only the zeros following the comma (`,001` to `,1` but `,010` to `,10`; it's not *remove 0's from the second column* but the example doesn't clearly show the requirement), you could replace the comma and zeros with another comma:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,0+/,",")}1' file
k141_173024,1
k141_173071,2
k141_173527,21
k141_173652,34
k141_173724,41
```

Answer (score 2):

If the second field is a number, you can do this to remove the leading zeroes:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 OFS int($2)}' file
```

As per @Inian's suggestion, this can be further simplified to:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$2=int($2)}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,0\+/,/' file
```

This removes leading zeroes from the second column by replacing a comma followed by one or more zeroes by a comma.

P.S. I guess the OP did not mean to remove zeroes that are part of the number.